# ASP.NET Web Application Target Framework 3.5, but Development Server Version Information says 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-development-serv

I set the Target Framework for a Web Application to .Net Framework 3.5, but when I get a YSOD, the "Version information" at the bottom of the page says "Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420"

I've replicated this on a File > New Web Application as well, so I can conclude that I'm not doing anything out of line in my code.

Does anyone know why this is, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 SP2 with some new assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ASP.Net 3.5.

.Net 3.5 is just a bunch of new DLLs, plus new versions of C# and VB.Net.
It's the same runtime.

Comment: That is to say that .NET Frameworks 3.0 and 3.5 were really just extension libraries for 2.0, whereas for instance .NET Framework 4.0 is a completely new set of libraries.

Answer (score -1):

In IIS change the application pool to target Framework 3.5

Comment: There is no "Framework 3.5" choice for an IIS Application Pool. Look at the previous answers.

Comment: Yes, I mistook the target Framework of WebConfig with ASP version in IIS, apologies.